# How do you set markers on items in Fortnite Battle Royale on Xbox?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In the recent Season 8 update, the ability to place markers on items, such as guns, meds, etc... has been added. I have tried to use this feature, but I cannot seem to find out how to use it. You cannot access this through the map, as it will just mark a location, and I do not know how to set markers without going to the map. Does anyone know how to access this feature for console players?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not changed your settings then it should be **left on the d-pad**.

There are many applications of this functionality:

- When aiming to place a marker on an enemy.
- While looking at guns/loot to place a marker on them.
- While looking at a place to place a marker on the location.

Placing a marker in the sky will cancel an existing location marker.

Answer (score 0):

R1 and L1 should by default set/remove markers. If you are using custom bind and your R1 and L1 have assigned other functions you will not be able to use markers quickly.

Comment: Can you answer how to do this for PC players too? I know its out of scope of the question, but I think it silly to create another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's LB and RB for removing and setting a marker on your **minimap** pressing left on your D-Pad while looking at an item/weapon will mark the weapon. Looking in a general direction will set a normal marker that **only people in your party can see.** Looking in a general direction and pressing Left on your D-Pad twice will set a marker titled 'DANGER' this marker will be red and will **also only be visible to players in your party.** The last one can be used to mark enemy sightings and bases.